Is there an easy way to split a large object into 3d printer-sized components without having to manually create 'dowels' for alignment?
I design objects destined for 3d printing. Some are too large. I would like to separate these objects into parts, but I typically add cylinders to form a 'dowel' on one part and a hole on the other. Is anyone aware of a tool or technique that makes this easier? Ideally, it would enable setting a gap (such as .1mm) as there is such a thing as too tight a fit.
The first pic is just separating a large part. The second is a frame I created with a bolt hole and an alignment peg to prevent twisting. I am looking for an automated technique for performing this action.
Thanks!



You need to be able to generate the dowels whole-cloth from an input mesh or you already have the dowel objects in the blender file and you need an easy way to integrate them into the models?

I have been generating them by creating a cylinder, duplicating it in place, and performing a bool difference on one side with the first cylinder and a join on the other side with the cylinder copy. On the join side, I reduce the diameter by .1 mm.  I just thought it'd be cool if you could autogenerate these dowels as an option in the separate function for an object.

So if you're okay with manually moving the dowels around, not having their placement be done automatically then this is pretty straightforward:
Make 3 collections and sort your objects like this.

Exploded view of the objects:

Then make a Geometry Nodes setup like this.

The result combines them all into one object with all of your operations done.
Exploded view of the final mesh:

